# How to map values from map to object based on containsKey?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a map of values like so:

```
Map<String, Object> values = Map.of("name", "myName", "address", null);
```

I want to update an object like this:

```
class User {
  String name;
  String address;
  String country;
}
```

Now I want the fields in `User` to be overwritten *only* if the source map has the key defined. So the `address` field should be set to null (because there's an explicit mapping to null), but the `country` field should not be changed (because there's no `"country"` key in the map).

This is similar to what `nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = IGNORE` does, but not quite, as the check is a `map.containsKey` check instead of a standard null check.

Can I extend MapStruct so it can do this?

My MapStruct code:

```
@Mapper
interface MyMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "name", expression = "java( from.getMap().get(\"name\") )")
    @Mapping(target = "address", expression = "java( from.getMap().get(\"address\") )")
    @Mapping(target = "country", expression = "java( from.getMap().get(\"country\") )")
    To get(MapWrapper from, @MappingTarget To to);
}
```

Comment: In `Map.of()` Instead of `address` you mean `"address"`, don't you?

Comment: Yup, thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapStruct can't do this out of the box.

However, you could wrap your Map into a Bean. So something like this:

```java
public class MapAccessor{

private Map<String, Object> mappings;

   public MapAccessor(Map<String, Object> mappings) {
      this.mappings = mappings;
   }

   public Object getAddress(){
       return this.mappings.get("address");
   }

   public boolean hasAddress(){
       return this.mappings.containsKey("address");
   }
   ... 
}
```

And then you could a normal mapper mapping `WrappedMap` to your targetbean and using the `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy`..

Note: your mapper is a lot simpler than as well..

```java
@Mapper( nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValueProperertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE )
interface MyMapper {

    To get(MapAccessor from, @MappingTarget To to);
}
```

Comment: then how do I distinguish between missing keys and keys mapped to `null` explicitly?

Comment: I adapted the case.. You should define that you skip values which are not found in the map

Comment: I still don't think this differentiates between a key mapped to `null` and a missing key. Both will resolve to `null` if you only use `map.get` and don't check `containsKey`, and hence both will be ignored. The explicitly mapped `null` should not be ignored.

Comment: So, you want to call a containsKey explicitly? Instead of letting the getAddress return null (which is used in a null check by MapStruct?) .. Use a presence checker.. I'll update the example.

Comment: Awesome, yes, that does cover the case correctly. The downside is that I'll have to write a non-trivial wrapper class for every single map, so it would still be awesome if this map behaviour could be supported out of the box!

Comment: There are some issues on our issue-list that request this functionality out of the box.. So. perhaps in the near future..